# Splitting a C++ string by new line without using string stream

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a string `"file1\nfile2\nfile3".`

I want to print out:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

How can I do this without using a string stream?

Note: When I say string, I mean the string object in C++.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question; I'm completely new to C++;

Comment: Why don't you just print out the string as is, without splitting it at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/most-elegant-way-to-split-a-string

Comment: `string s = "file1\nfile2\nfile3"; cout << s << '\n';`

Comment: Crap. So much for my proposed programming text: Learn C++ in 365 years.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work and lets you specify a multichar delim:

```
void split_and_print(const std::string & data, const std::string & delim =std::string{"\n"}){
    if (!delim.length()){
        std::cout<<data<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    auto last  = data.begin();
    auto found = last;
    while (found != data.end()){
        found = std::search(last, data.end(), delim.begin(), delim.end());
        std::cout<<std::string(last, found)std::endl;
        last = found + delim.length();   
    }
}
```